# How to process an excel file more efficiently?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, performance, excel, file-upload

I have an excel file that enters through my MVC web app that I have to process and do things with. So I receive my file on the controller

```
public class StripExcelDocument 
{
    public DataSet Convert(HttpPostedFileBase file)
        {
            return GetDataFromExcel(file.InputStream);
        }

        private DataSet GetDataFromExcel(Stream target)
        {
            var excelReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(target);
            excelReader.IsFirstRowAsColumnNames = true;
            return excelReader.AsDataSet();
        }
}
```

and I send it through a processor I have created that is just a large conditional statement and then based on the outcome it gets sent to a specific table in a database.

```
 public class Processor{
      public Result Process
      {
            if (FirstCondition(string foo, int bar)){
                SetResult(foo, bar);
                }

            if (SecondCondition(string foo, int bar)){
                SetResult(foo, bar);
                }

            if (ThirdCondition(string foo, int bar)){
                SetResult(foo, bar);
                }

                //etc...
```

Obviously this works great when the user wants to enter a single record but when processing large excel files it either:

A: Times out on the server.
B: Leaves the user staring at a screen for a while.

What is a more effective way to deal with bulk processing large amounts of data from an excel file, where the records will need to be their own entity in the database?

Comment: Does the user need to wait for this processing to complete? If not you could delegate it to some out-of-process service that will perform the necessary task and notify the user that his request has been accepted for processing. An additional benefit with this approach is that you will off-load your ASP.NET worker threads to do what they do best (serve user requests) instead of parsing Excel files and updating databases.

Comment: The next step in the user's process is to deal with any of the records that did not meet an approval step. At that point the user has nothing to do until the record has been proccessed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to keep it as last option. Because `SqlBulkCopy` belongs to some older versions of .net and may be there are some better things available now.

> 1. Do the Bulk Import for all the records of excel sheet in some table. So you can use SqlBulkCopy.
> 2. Create a Stored proc and based upon the conditions, use the Insert/Update in one shot.

The above approach in Stored proc will be faster as comparing to Linq operations in code behind.

> A: Times out on the server. B: Leaves the user staring at a screen for
>   a while.

Do it asynchronously.

### **Example Code**

```
class ThreadTest
{
  public ActionResult Main()
  {
    Thread t = new Thread (WriteY);
    t.Start();         
    return View();
  }

  void WriteY()
  {

  }
}
```

**For TimeOut**

`sqlcommand.CommandTimeout = 0` will set it to infinite

Comment: I still need to run the records through some form of processor, even if I don't use my created one. There is a lengthy condition to decide the end result of the record